Android viewpager2 + viewpager2 + webview
In viewpager2, the item of vp2 at the innermost part of viewpager2 is webview. How to handle sliding conflicts, prioritize responding to webview's sliding, followed by the parent vp2, and finally handle the top-level vp2
Priority is given to responding to the sliding of the webview, followed by the parent viewpager2, and finally the top-level viewpager2 for processing
